# How to join catalog product collection to custom collection

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make join on my **custom module collection to product collection**.In my module there is a single table which have product sku and product url key.Now I want all catalog product data as well as my module data below is the code which i am using but it's not working :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
                $msa_eventType = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('preview/preview');              
                $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('review'=>$msa_eventType),'`main_table`.`sku` = `review`.`sku`',array('product_name'));
```

Comment: first check $msa_eventType return table value or not?

Comment: Add echo `$collection->getSelect(); die;` after Join and share the SQL generated by magento.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **`** from your query,

```
'`main_table`.`sku` = `review`.`sku`'
```

Replace it with

```
'main_table.sku = review.sku'
```

Final code,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$msa_eventType = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('preview/preview');              
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('review'=>$msa_eventType),'main_table.sku = review.sku',array('product_name'));
```